# How can i make an exception on "caused by SendMultiMediaRequest"?

Tags: python, asynchronous, exception, telethon

How can i make an exception on "A wait of 61 seconds is required (caused by SendMultiMediaRequest)" ? I can't find anything in the official documentation.
The fact is that when sending photos to some users, this error pops up.

Basically sends well, but sometimes there are users who simply do not send (throws an exception "Exception"), although they exist and, in principle, you can send a message to them. I need to trace this exception

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, errors

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

message = "Hello"
files = ['img/11.jpg', 'img/22.jpg', 'img/33.jpg', 'img/44.jpg', 'img/55.jpg']


async def main():
    for user in db.get_users(name_table=table):
        try:
            if db.check_invited(name_table=table, user_name=user) != "TRUE":
                await client.send_message(entity=user, message=message, file=files)
                print('Ok')

        except errors.BadRequestError as e:
            print(e)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing the code?

Comment: The error sounds like you are hitting a flood limit. You will need to slow down or run it less often to prevent it.